# Django graphql auth not showing all user fields in mutation

Tags: django, graphql

I have followed below tutorial to introduce user authentication in my django app.

https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/

It has created the user mutations as below,

[Graphql user mutation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbjC8.png)

The mutation to update user shows only two fields, first name and last name. However my user model has other fields as well like is_staff, is_superuser, gender.

I would like to get control on updating those fields as well.

Please advise how can I get that done?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding below code to the app settings,

```
GRAPHQL_AUTH['UPDATE_MUTATION_FIELDS'] = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'is_staff',
    'is_active',
    'gender',
    ]
```